# Right Outer join issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, join, outer-join

I've two tables that I want to join and filter data from. I used a stored procedure to do that. My intention is to bring every item from the second table (i.e Department) even if they don't have a matching record in the first table (i.e. Employee) and finally display the count. Here is the segment of the code I used:

```
select d.deptName, 
case when COUNT(*) is null then '0' else count(*) end AS total 
from Employee e 
right outer join Department d on e.deptID=d.deptID 
WHERE e.Year=@year
and e.Month=@month
group by d.deptName
order by d.deptName
```

But, it's not displaying what i wanted and failed to figure out the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply the filter condition through `where` clause after `join`, it filters out all the records which doesn't satisfy the filter criteria. Try moving your filter criteria in join condition itself as below:

```
   select d.deptName, 
         case when COUNT(*) is null then '0' else count(*) end AS total 
   from Employee e 
   right outer join Department d 
      on (e.Year=@year 
          and e.Month=@month
          and e.deptID=d.deptID)
   group by d.deptName
   order by d.deptName
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the code like this

```
SELECT d.deptName, COUNT(e.deptID) AS total
   FROM Employee e
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN Department d
      ON (e.Year= @year 
          AND e.Month= @month
          AND e.deptID=d.deptID)
   GROUP BY d.deptName
   ORDER BY d.deptName
```

See the SQL Fiddle for the query : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1105/17